# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. When installing Cassandra on Docker on Linux Lite

Tags: linux, docker, cassandra, installation

When installing Cassandra on Docker on Linux Lite after entering:

curl https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -

then I get:

gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Answer (score 9):

I also got the same issue.
Actually this URL return `404` when executed so I tried this URL in browser
`https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS` and it is redirected to this URL
`https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS`.

So, I changed the URL in the command

> curl https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -

to this

> curl https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in an  Docker container. I believe the cause was that the container was missing CA certs.

apt-get update

apt-get install ca-certificates

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I know it depends on the version of python installed. I have version 2.7.17. If I had 2.5.15 or earlier I wouldn't have a problem turning on cqlsh

Answer (score 0):

I got an error like this same issue. I was also getting the `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.` error. So I changed the URL a bit because I discovered it wasn't pointing to the exact gpg file.

`curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu | sudo apt-key add -`

to this

`curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

and I got 'OK' as output.